# Load images from gallery in the order the images were taken?

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to load images from my phones gallery: [MultiImageChooser](https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser/blob/master/src/com/forgottensystems/multiimagechooserV2/ImageFetcher.java)

It works well but the images load in reverse order of when they were created. Can someone look at the look and tell me:

- Which part loads the images?
- How I can reverse it?

I have been trying to figure it out for an hour but it seems to be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in the `ImageFetcher` class, but the `MultiImageChooserActivity` class.

If you take a look at [`onCreateLoader()`](https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser/blob/master/src/com/forgottensystems/multiimagechooserV2/MultiImageChooserActivity.java#L346), you'll see this line:

```
cl = new CursorLoader(MultiImageChooserActivity.this, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            img.toArray(new String[img.size()]), null, null, null);
```

The last parameter of [that constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#CursorLoader%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) is `sortOrder`. This is a standard SQL `ORDER BY` clause you can use to sort it with. With null passed in, it defaults to sorting by display name. You'll probably want to use [`DATE_TAKEN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html#DATE_TAKEN), ascending.